# filtrar vista por usuario en DJANGO

Tags: django, django-views

Me gustaría poder filtrar la vista según el usuario, específicamente según un campo de usuario (autorizado), ya logré filtrar la vista según unos filtros indicados en un queryset,

Ejemplo, primero filtro la vista según el campo =1 (campo de registro) pero quiero agregar que si el usuario es =1 (autorizado) lo muestra, si el usuario es =2 (no autorizado) no.

```
class ListadoReclamacion(ListView):
model = Rec

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(estado_cod=1,del_dep_code=self.request.user.cod_delegacion_zona.cod_delegacion)
```

Comment: Welcome peya02 This is Stack Overflow **in spanish**. Perhaps you wanted to pot this on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Hola peya02, estas en SOes, un sitio en español, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la traduzcas, para que sea mejor recibida y evitar los votos negativos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo la vista con los filtros creados dependiendo del usuario que accedí, però lo que quisera es modificar la url de un boton que aparece en la vista.
Si es usuario1 pasarle una url al boton y si es usuario2 pasarle otra.
¿es posible?
Vista que tengo actualmente:

```
class ListadoReclamacion(ListView):
model = Rec

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.cod_cargo_id==3:
        return self.model.objects.filter(estado_cod=4,del_dep_code=self.request.user.cod_delegacion_zona.cod_delegacion)
    else:
        return self.model.objects.filter(estado_cod=1,del_dep_code=self.request.user.cod_delegacion_zona.cod_delegacion)

def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        return HttpResponse(serialize('json',self.get_queryset()),'application/json')
    else:
        return redirect('inicio_reclamaciones')
```

Comment: Este es SOes. Las respuestas deben ser en español.